# Export data does not allow newlines c#

Tags: c#, xml, export

I export data form XML with results:

```
cu302
cu1701
cd1701
cc432
```

I wana show resuilts:
,cu302,cu1701

Is there any solution for the text to not have a line break?

+Add more question:
In XML file with content:

```
<ns1:TestXML name="1:u302">
<ns1:IndictmentXML algorithm="s192059844" indictmentType="Billboarding">
<ns1:RepairActionXML repairOperator="c_admin" repairTime="2021-01-21T07:45:58.000+07:00" repairActionType="-" indictmentType="Billboarding" comment="-" repairStatus="Repaired"/>
<ns1:ComponentXML packageId="192059844" partId="192059844" designator="1:u302"/>
</ns1:IndictmentXML>
</ns1:TestXML>
<ns1:TestXML name="1:d1701">
<ns1:IndictmentXML algorithm="bdiode-cr316" indictmentType="Wrong Polarity">
<ns1:RepairActionXML repairOperator="c_admin" repairTime="2021-01-21T07:45:51.000+07:00" repairActionType="-" indictmentType="Wrong Polarity" comment="-" repairStatus="False Call"/>
</ns1:IndictmentXML>
</ns1:TestXML>
```

how to sort tag ,how to filter out the results of: Repaired and False Call?
Please help me advice

Comment: Is your result a string or list/collection? If its a string, use the Replace method, `result.Replace(Environment.Newline, ",")`

Comment: That is not actual XML. Where are you exporting from? Where is your code to do so? What is your input and expected output?

Comment: You should [edit] the code into your post. You need `sw.Write` not `WriteLine`. **And this has nothing whatsoever to do with XML**

Comment: Don't add code in comments.  Edit your question, add the XML (the whole XML) and show your code there.  Code like that doesn't belong in a comment

Comment: ok, thanks bro. but you can help me convert XML to text file with format below?. I've post code. Please help me !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a empty string and add each line data to it:

```
var result = string.Empty;
foreach (XElement ComponentXML in doc.Descendants(ns1 + "ComponentXML"))
       foreach (var cRD in ComponentXML.Attributes("designator"))
               result += $"c{cRD.Value.Substring(2)}, ";

sw.writeLine(result)
```

Comment: Thanks bro so much! I update add more question. please see and help me advice fix it